# TimeoutException Traceback (most recent call last)

Tags: python

Im having this problem with this code, when y try to get a ID by xpath it wont let me

TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [118], line 2
1 wait=WebDriverWait(driver,20)
----> 2 wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="_id0:logon:USERNAME"]')))

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py:90, in WebDriverWait.until(self, method, message)
88     if time.monotonic() > end_time:
89         break
---> 90 raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

TimeoutException: Message:
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver from
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

s=Service('webdriver//chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = s)

driver.get('http://190.109.11.66:8888/BOE/BI')
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="_id0:logon:USERNAME"]')))
```

I tried several solutions and didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Try to except the error

```
from selenium import webdriver from
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time 
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

s=Service('webdriver//chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = s)

try;
    driver.get('http://190.109.11.66:8888/BOE/BI')
    wait=WebDriverWait(driver,20)
    time.sleep(5) # give selenium a sleep time
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="_id0:logon:USERNAME"]')))
except TimeoutException:
    pass
```